# How can I plot the monthly average temperature?

Tags: python

I wrote this code in order to obtain a series of monthly weather observations at Helsinki for a period from 1960 to 2020 and then I saved the data to a local file using package pickle. I used the data available from the API provided by Finnish Meteorological Institute.

```
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import pickle
import pandas as pd

class FmiApi:
    """
    a minimalistic wrapper for the Finnish Meteorological Institute API    
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs'
        self.fixed_params = {
                'service': 'WFS',
                'version':'2.0.0',
                }
        self.namespaces ={
                'wfs':'http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0',
                'gml':'http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2',
                'BsWfs':'http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0'
                }                   
    

try:
    with open('wdata.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        data=pickle.load(f)
        
except:
    wheaters=[]
    for year in range(1960,2021):  
            for month in range(1,13):
                api = FmiApi()
                w = api.get_monthly_obs('helsinki', year, month )
                
                wheaters.append(w)
                pprint(w)
                
    with open('wdata.pkl', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(wheaters, f)
```

Now I want to use the local file to access the data in order to plot the monthly average temperature for the years 1960 to 2020.
I wrote this code but it doesn't print the average temperature:

```
def get_data(file_in=None, file_out=None):

    assert file_in != None or file_out != None
    
    #read wdata from local file 
    df_weath = pd.read_csv('wdata.pkl', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)   
    df_weath.sort_values('Date', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
    df_weath['Date'] = df_weath['Date'].dt.date   #convert to datetime objects

    #print(df_wdata)
    #input()
   
    #get weather data in the format returned by the api
    if file_in != None:  #read weather data from local file
        with open(file_in, 'rb') as f:
            wdata = pickle.load(f)
    else:   #use the FMI API to get weather data
        api = FmiApi()  #instantiate the api
        params = {            
                'place': u'helsinki',                       
                'maxlocations': '5',
                }
        d0 = df_weath['date'].values[0]
        d1 = df_weath['date'].values[-1]
        n_days = (d1 - d0).days + 1  #number of days between d0 and d1
        wdata = []
        for i_day in range(n_days):  
            date = d0 + datetime.timedelta(days=i_day)
            params['starttime'] = str(date) + 'T00:00:00'
            params['endtime'] = str(date) + 'T00:00:00'
            try:
                print('requesting weather data for %s'%str(date))
                weather = api.get_daily_obs(params)                                
            except:                
                print('getting weather failed, skipping')
                continue
            wdata.append(weather)
            
        if file_out != None:    #save weather data to a file
            with open(file_out, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(wdata, f)
        
     #move weather data to a pandas dataframe (calculate avg over valid observations)
    data = []
    variables = ['tday'] 
    for wobs in wdata:        
        avgs = {}
        for pos, obs in wobs.items():                   
            for var, xx in obs.items():                
                if not var in variables: continue
                sdate = xx[1][:10]
                date = datetime.date(*[int(z) for z in sdate.split('-')])            
                if xx[0] != 'NaN':
                    val = float(xx[0])                    
                else:
                    val = None
                if not var in avgs: avgs[var] = []  
                if val != None: avgs[var].append(val)       
        vals = []
        for var in variables:  #calculate the average when available
            if len(avgs[var]) > 0:
                vals.append(sum(avgs[var])/len(avgs[var]))
            else:
                vals.append(None)
        row = [date] + vals   
        data.append(row)         
    df_weather = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date'] + variables)
    
    print(df_weather)
    input()
    
    #merge the dataframes by date (pick dates from weather df and add NaNs for missing values)
    df = pd.merge(df_weather, df_weath, on='date', how='left', sort=True)   
    return df
```

The dictionary is like this:

```
{(65.90051, 29.06302): {'rrmon': ('18.4', '1985-01-01T00:00:00Z'),
                        'tmon': ('NaN', '1985-01-01T00:00:00Z')},
 (65.91718, 29.22969): {'rrmon': ('15.0', '1985-01-01T00:00:00Z'),
                        'tmon': ('NaN', '1985-01-01T00:00:00Z')},
 (65.95515, 29.1347): {'rrmon': ('16.9', '1985-01-01T00:00:00Z'),
                       'tmon': ('NaN', '1985-01-01T00:00:00Z')}}
```

Can you help me to find what I am doing wrong? Or do you know any easier way to plot the monthly average temperature?

Comment: "It's not working" does not constitute a valid question on SO. Please see [ask] and [MCVE]. Basic debugging is your responsibility.

Comment: Try to Focus your question by adding a small part of the dataframe and the Error or a picture of the results you are getting.

Comment: I added a small part of the dataframe. My code doesn't print anything so I can't show you the results.

Comment: Your sample dataframe is not a dataframe but a dictionary with embedded dictionaries?

Comment: yeah, it is the output of a part of the code and then I saved it to a local file. Probably what is wrong in my code is the part where I need to extract the information from the pkl file I created.